# Using map reduce in CouchDB to output fewer rows

Tags: database, join, dictionary, couchdb, reduce

Lets say you have two document types, *customers* and *orders*. A *customer* document contains basic information like name, address etc. and *orders* contain all the order information each time a customer orders something. When storing the documents, the type = order or the type = customer.

If I do a map function over a set of 10 customers and 30 orders it will output 40 rows. Some rows will be customers, some will be orders.

The question is, how do I write the reduce, so that the order information is *"stuffed"* inside of the rows that has the customer information? So it will return 10 rows (10 customers), but all the relevant orders for each customer.

Basically I don't want separate records on the output, I want to combine them (orders into one customer row) and I think reduce is the way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is called **view collation** and it is a very useful CouchDB technique.

Fortunately, you don't even need a `reduce` step. Just use `map` to get the customers and their orders "clumped" together.

### Setup

The key is that you need a unique id for each customer, and it has to be known both from customer docs and from order docs.

Example customer:

```
{ "_id": "customer me@example.com"
, "type": "customer"
, "name": "Jason"
}
```

Example order:

```
{ "_id": "abcdef123456"
, "type": "order"
, "for_customer": "customer me@example.com"
}
```

I have conveniently used the customer ID as the document `_id` but the important thing is that *both docs know the customer's identity*.

### Payoff

The goal is a map query, where if you specify `?key="customer me@example.com"` then you will get back (1) first, the customer info, and (2) any and all orders placed.

This map function would do that:

```
function(doc) {
  var CUSTOMER_VAL = 1;
  var ORDER_VAL    = 2;
  var key;

  if(doc.type === "customer") {
    key = [doc._id, CUSTOMER_VAL];
    emit(key, doc);
  }

  if(doc.type === "order") {
    key = [doc.for_customer, ORDER_VAL];
    emit(key, doc);
  }
}
```

All rows will sort primarily on the customer the document is about, and the "tiebreaker" sort is either the integer 1 or 2. That makes customer docs always sort above their corresponding order docs.

```
["customer me@example.com", 1], ...customer doc...
["customer me@example.com", 2], ...customer's order...
["customer me@example.com", 2], ...customer's other order.
... etc...
["customer another@customer.com", 1], ... different customer...
["customer another@customer.com", 2], ... different customer's order
```

P.S. If you follow all that: instead of `1` and `2` a better value might be `null` for the customer, then the order timestamp for the order. They will sort identically as before except now you have a chronological list of orders.

Comment: +1 This is explained on [CouchDB wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Examples), but you have added some useful tip.

Comment: Right I understand this aspect of it, but lets say you want to output the result set to a table... and you want everything on 1 row.. customer name, list of orders, next row... 2nd customer, list of orders... if you're looping through the records as you suggest... some of the rows would 'only be customers' and some rows would 'only be orders'.... my question is how to combine it during a loop so that you can get back 10 customers (10 rows ) with the orders combined in that for loop.  View collation solves the grouping, but it still makes 'extra rows'

Comment: Good point, Matt. A `_list` function can do that--it's slightly hacky but might work. Simply maintain an array of "real" customer-order rows. When you see a customer row that *also* has orders below it, add it to the final result. Then send that through. A better answer is with reduce. If you write up your question (how to "merge" view collation into useful output) then I will detail both the `_list` and `reduce` methods.

Comment: yes would be interested in learning more about this... I have just added a new question so hopefully this can be addressed.  TIA!

Comment: And the new question seems to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084741/merge-view-collation-into-useful-output-in-couchdb